# How do I make this query work? or is there any alternative query for this

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblFuelTypeLookUp 
WHERE (strChassis, strMake, strModel) IN (
           ('F2DLZF', 'Audi', 'A6'),
           ('F8CXYF', 'Audi', 'A8'),
           ('F8CXYL', 'Audi', 'A8'),
           ('F2DKNF', 'Audi', 'A6 Avant'),
           ('F8CWWF', 'Audi', 'S8'),
           ('F2DJPL', 'Audi', 'S6'))
```

error message : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Comment: And could you please specify database you use

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: The `IN()` clause contains a list of comma separated values/elements in parentheses. Your elements happen to be whole tuples - that is, three literals, comma separated, in round parentheses. Put the whole list into a pair of outmost parentheses.

Comment: The `IN` operator in SQL Server doesn't accept tuples like that. Have you considered using a `JOIN` on a `VALUES TABLE`? They're not just for `INSERT` statements.

Comment: marcothesane is right; there are paranetheses missing for this syntax. And AlwaysLearning is also right; SQL Server doesn't support IN with tuples anyway. Joining a values table is a good idea. The other option would be clumsy AND/OR combinations (`WHERE (strChassis = 'F2DLZF' AND strMake = 'Audi' AND strModel = 'A6') OR (strChassis = 'F8CXYF' AND ...`.

Comment: Thanks everyone.I think this is shortest way this query works :

Comment: SELECT * FROM tblFuelTypeLookUp where 
(strChassis ='F2DLZF'and strMake = 'Audi'and strModel = 'A6')  OR
(strChassis ='F8CXYF'and strMake = 'Audi'and strModel = 'A8')  OR
(strChassis ='F8CXYL'and strMake = 'Audi'and strModel = 'A8')

Comment: You can join on a `VALUES` clause https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1ad06b6a7e7be93c3746b4c0f77935d

Comment: Thanks Charlieface, it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I would untuple the tuples by do the following code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblFuelTypeLookUp 
WHERE (strChassis like 'F2DLZF' and strMake like 'Audi' and strModel like 'A6')
or (strChassis like 'F8CXYF' and strMake like 'Audi' and strModel like 'A8')
or (strChassis like 'F8CXYL' and strMake like 'Audi' and strModel like 'A8')
or (strChassis like 'F2DKNF' and strMake like 'Audi' and strModel like 'A6 Avant')
or (strChassis like 'F8CWWF' and strMake like 'Audi' and strModel like 'S8')
or (strChassis like 'F2DJPL' and strMake like 'Audi' and strModel like 'S6')
```